# Where can you find JDK9 build 174 for eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I've been trying to get Eclipse Oxygen working with JDK9. 
Apparently, the current release of Oxygen has only been tested on JDK9 build 174. It is not guaranteed to work with earlier or later build of JDK9.

The current build of JDK9 is 181. And it is not working with Eclipse. 
I've been trying to add JDK to my existing project. And it is not working. 
I want to try whether it works with JDK9 build 174 for Windows. And I can't find it anywhere.

Someone please help me...

[image]

Comment: I think you could reword your question, to something like "why is eclipse restricted to certain versions of Java9" - to then also improve your self-answer. As of now, you are simply asking for an offsite resource - which makes your question off topic. When you reword to "why does eclipse not work with newer Java9" or something alike ... you end up with something *in* the scope of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem, only installing the Eclipse Oxygen is not enough, you need to go into the Marketplace and install the Java 9 support package. 
Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the Azul / zulu version. Older versions are still available. jdk9u176 == zulu 9.0.0.13.

See http://zulu.org/zulu-9-pre-release-downloads/

Windows version: http://cdn.azul.com/zulu-pre/bin/zulu9.0.0.13-ea-jdk9.0.0-win_x64.zip

Comment: Just tried... Still doesn't work

Comment: Then there is another issue with your setup. u176 and u174 are very similar, see http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-June/005910.html. You should specify the exact problem you have. "Does not work" is not very useful :)